# how widget is created only through script

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, web-applications, widget

I have come across few chat application and the website which I don't know how these things work. can someone tell me how these application works in the website.

I have seen some website with a chat widget for helping the customer for respective to their business. On signing in these application, a script file is send to email, when it is pasted over the website. Automatically a widget is created. And this widget and the application is connected externally.
Sorry, if my question is not clear. I will give some links of application and website which give you some idea what I'm trying to ask.

Website

1. `http://www.a1000yoga.com/`
2. `http://www.voyzek.com/contact-us/`

Application

1. `https://www.zopim.com/`
2. `https://my.livechatinc.com/`

Comment: try to learn Nodejs .

Comment: Does only node js can give these type of features or through any other programming language we can achieve these features.

Comment: only node js is efficient.

Comment: you are talking about script . actually they created Api for user i the form of script. so you can directly use the widgets.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is called providing **Web API**,

Wikipedia's definition of Web API is  :

> A server-side web API is a programmatic interface consisting of one or
>   more publicly exposed endpoints to a defined request-response message
>   system, typically expressed in JSON or XML, which is exposed via the
>   web—most commonly by means of an HTTP-based web server. Mashups are
>   web applications which combine the use of multiple server-side web
>   APIs.

In brief, They implement their service in their servers, and let you access their services by HTTP requests.

You sign up in their website and they generate a API token(a random string maybe), then when you want use their services, you send them your requests with your API token as authentication or identifying mean, and they process your request throw their application and with your data on their servers, and send you respond.

For example when you use this messaging services(or Captchas, Ads networks, etc), they provide a piece of Javascript containing your API code, then when someone views your web page, the code will send request with your API token to API provider servers and they process data for you.

You can then access to your data through their website, another API, email or etc.